# iSCSI LUN, more than one intitator

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, iscsi, synology

I am experimenting for the first time with iSCSI. I ´ve setup a Synology DS1513+, target and LUN configured, first initiator (WS 2008) configured, copied some folders on it, everything works fine.

Now, I went and configured a second intiator (WS 2012), connected to the same target, but somehow I can´t see the LUN. It just shows me an empty volume. I need to know what it is that I need to configure to see the folders on both initiators.

Answer (score 1):

You normally cannot do this because if you map a LUN on a non-cluster filesystem you can very easily corrupt the volume.

However, on your diskstation you can select the "allow multiple sessions" box when you're viewing the iSCSI target settings.

Comment: I already did, actually. The status window shows both initiators connected. But, I only see my data on the first initiator.